# Variable reference inside SQLSyntax when constructing SQL query in ScalalikeJdbc

Tags: scala

I have a search parameter from request which is a string like "abc". Now I want to build an sqls and use this variable reference inside the sqls. I tried below approach:

```
val searchValue = "abc"    

sqls"column_name ILIKE '%$searchValue%'"
```

**But this didn't work**. Then i tried with below unsafe approach.

```
val searchValueSqls = SQLSyntax.createUnsafely(searchValue)

sqls"column_name ILIKE '%$searchValueSqls%'"
```

This worked fine but documentation says **"Be aware of SQL injection vulnerability."**

***Is there any safe approach to achieve variable reference inside sqls?***

Another approach is that we can use **sqls.like** to build the like operation.

But ***is sqls.like case insensitive?*** As **ILIKE** is case insensitive for redshift.

Comment: maybe `sqls"column_name ILIKE '%${searchValue}%'"`?

Comment: All works properly https://scastie.scala-lang.org/optician/VLzFbqQwQxaCGAfWqiIu7w Plz, specify versions and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use **[LikeConditionEscapeUtil](https://github.com/scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc/blob/3.0.1/scalikejdbc-core/src/test/scala/scalikejdbc/LikeConditionEscapeUtilSpec.scala)**.

```
val escapedValue = SQLSyntax.createUnsafely(LikeConditionEscapeUtil.escape(searchValue))
sqls"column_name ILIKE '$escapedValue'"
```